# Uniform convergence of $f_n(x)=\frac{\sqrt{1+{(nx)}^2}}{n}$ and ${f_n}^\prime$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Discuss the uniform convergence of $f_n(x)=\frac{\sqrt{1+{(nx)}^2}}{n}$ and its first derivative on real line.

I think both $f_n$ and ${f_n}^\prime$ do not converge uniformly. If we put $x=0,1$ in $f_n$ then we get point wise limit 0 and 1 respectively. So $f_n$ doesn't converge uniformly.

Now, 
${f_n}^\prime(x)=\frac{nx}{\sqrt{1+(nx)^2}}.$ If we put $x=1/n$ then it becomes $1/\sqrt{2}$ . So sup norm never becomes zero. But point wise limit is zero. So it is not uniformly convergent. Correct? Thanks.

Comment: Your answer for $f_n$ is incorrect. You have proved that there are two points $x,y$ such that $f_n(x)$ and $f_n(y)$ converge to different values, but this doesn't mean the convergence is non-uniform. It turns out that $f_n$ *does* converge uniformly. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're answer for $f_n$ is NOT correct actually. The functions $f_n$ do converge uniformly to the function $f(x) = \lvert x \rvert $. Indeed, we see that $$f_n(x) = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n^2} + x^2}$$ and thus using the inequality $$\lvert b \rvert \le \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} \le \lvert a \rvert + \lvert b \rvert,$$ which holds for all $a,b\in \mathbb R$, we have  $$\lvert x \rvert \le f_n(x) \le \frac 1 n + \lvert x \rvert, \,\,\,\,\,\,\, \forall x \in\mathbb R.$$ Sending $n \to \infty$ clearly shows that $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f(x) = \lvert x \rvert$ on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Ohh thank you very much. Nice idea. First it seems like $f_n$ converges point wise to 1 except at $x=0$. But if we think deeply than we realize it is uniformly convergent.

Comment: This example also serves as a sequence of continuously differentiable functions converging to a function which is not continuously differentiable (not even differentiable).

Answer (score 2):

Pointwise limit of $f_n'(x)$ is $0$ for $x=0$, $1$ for $x >0$ and $-1$ for $x<0$. The limit function is not continuous and  hence the convergence of $(f_n')$ is not uniform.

Comment: Am I correct about$f_n$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy The answer is actually incorrect for $f_n$. See my answer below.