# Prove that $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$ but $\{f_n^\prime\}$ does not.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Consider $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ defined by $$f_n (x) = \frac{\sqrt{1 + (nx)^2}}{n}$$.

Prove that $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$ but $\{f_n^\prime\}$ does not.

I have shown that $f_n \rightarrow |x|$ pointwise. But how to proceed for uniform convergence?

I want to do it without using basic definition of uniform convergence. There are so many tests like Weiesrtrass M-test.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** Let $f(x) = |x|$. By noting that

$$ f_n(x) - f(x)
= \frac{\sqrt{1+(nx)^2} - n|x|}{n}
= \frac{1}{n\left(\sqrt{1+(nx)^2} + n|x|\right)} $$

and that $\sqrt{1+(nx)^2} + n|x| \geq 1$ holds for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, we have

$$ \left| f_n(x) - f(x) \right| \leq \frac{1}{n} $$

uniformly in $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and hence the uniform convergence of $(f_n)$ to $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$ is established.

**2.** On the other hand, if $(f_n')$ converges uniformly to some function on $g$ on $\mathbb{R}$, then

- Since each $f_n'$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, we know that $g$ must be continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ as well.
- By the theorem about uniform convergence and differentiability, it must be the case that the uniform limit $f$ of $f_n$ is also differentiable and $f' = g$ holds.

Now, since $f(x) = |x|$ is not differentiable, we have a contradiction and therefore $(f_n')$ cannot converge uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. You wrote $\left| f_n(x) - f(x) \right| \leq \frac{1}{n}$ is uniformly in  $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and  the uniform convergence  is established.  Can you please explain it more explicitly? Thanks.

Comment: @user454229, With that inequality in your hand, could you explain what troubles you from applying the definition of (or any related results about) the uniform convergence?

Comment: Is this about the following: since  $\left| f_n(x) - f(x) \right| \leq \frac{1}{n}$ we have $M_n = \text{sup} _{x \in \mathbb{R}} |f_n (x)- f(x)| <\frac{1}{n}$. Also we always have $M_n >0$. Therefore, $0< M_n < \frac{1}{n}$, i.e.,$ M_n = 0$. So, $f_n \rightarrow f$ uniformly. Am I right?

Comment: @user454229, That is the correct direction, but your argument needs some calibration. Note that the inequality only tells you $M_n\leq\frac{1}{n}$ (and in fact, we can check that $M_n=\frac{1}{n}$ although this is not necessary for our purpose). Also, you don't need to check if $M_n>0$ or not. All you need is whether $M_n \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ or not, and the inequality $M_n\leq\frac{1}{n}$ is enough for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

$|f_n(x)-|x||=\frac 1 {n^{2}{\sqrt {\frac 1 {n^{2}}+x^{2}}+|x|}}\leq \frac 1  n$. For non-uniformity of convergence of $f_n'$, show that $f_n'(x) \to 1$ if $x>0$ and $f_n'(x) \to -1$  if $x<0$. Since the limit is not continuous it follows that the convergence is not uniform.

Comment: You answered an identical question before: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3046076/42969.